# A word to convey "online-ness"

Tags: synonyms

To give some context, in the algorithm design world there are two kinds of algorithms, *online* ones (which can work with partial amounts of data as it becomes available), and *offline* ones (which need the whole data to be present before starting).

I'd like to say something along the lines of *"online-ness of the algorithm is not an objective at this time"*, but "online-ness" just hits my ear wrong.

Are there any alternatives?

Note that this is not the same as "available", is more along the lines of "streaming" (but, in the context I'm working on, "streaming" is already established to mean something totally different).

Comment: This seems to me (especially in the light of the first answer) to relate to specific technical terminology, and I question whether this is the appropriate forum for it>

Comment: I'd be happy to move it to some other place, do you care to suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, also a fellow CS, perhaps you can add a verb to the adjective 'online'? You could enumerate your non-objectives as:

> - Constant space
> - Sub-logarithmic running time
> - Online processing

Answer (score 2):

Fellow CS guy here, so I know what you're going for with "online". You need to keep exactly that word so that you're being precise in what you're saying. In cases like that, I just structure the sentence around the word. I'd say something like

"Designing an online algorithm was not an objective of this research/project/assignment."

Comment: A pleasure to meet another one of us in here :)

The thing is that I'm enumerating non-objectives, so I already have things like "constant space" and "sub-logarithmic running time" and the like :S

Comment: Ah, I see. The simplest thing would be to say something like "The following were not objectives for this algorithm: online operation, sub logarithmic run time, and use of constant space."  Maybe start with that and modify to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Working with one dimensional data, you can use one of the acceptions of **recursivity**, for which you can find examples in the FFT, an offline implementation of the discrete Fourier transform (DFT), and the sliding or recursive DFT, its online version.